# Hi, I am creating a simpleplatformer game with love2d, I got a problem in the collisions

Tags: lua, collision-detection, game-development, collision, love2d

In my player script. I called a function to check is if a tile is collided with the player.

The basic tile collisions has been made, but I got some problems.

1. When the player jump while colliding with the wall, the player stop.
2. When the player is falling while colliding with the wall, the player stop.

I think the problem is in the Y collision checking part, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
--------------------- Collision Check ----------------------

local box = Vt2:new(self.pos.x + self.vel.x * dt * self.dirXTemp, 
            self.pos.y + self.vel.y * dt)

for i = 1, #collTile do

    local tile = collTile[i]

    local isColl = BdBoxCollision(box, self.size, tile.pos, tile.size)

    if 
        isColl[1] == true and
        isColl[2] == true and
        isColl[3] == true and
        isColl[4] == true then

        local isOnWall = false

        if self.pos.y + self.size.y > tile.pos.y then -- X Collision 

            if box.x + self.size.x / 2 < tile.pos.x + tile.size.x / 2 then
                
                if box.x + self.size.x > tile.pos.x  then
                    
                    if self.dirX == 1 then
                        self.vel.x = 0
    
                        isOnWall = true
                    end

                end

            end

            if box.x + self.size.x / 2 > tile.pos.x + tile.size.x / 2 then
                
                if box.x < tile.pos.x + tile.size.x then
                    
                    if self.dirX == -1 then
                        self.vel.x = 0
                    
                        isOnWall = true
                    end

                end

            end

        end

        if box.y + self.size.y / 2 < tile.pos.y + tile.size.y / 2 then -- Y Collision

            if box.y + self.size.y > tile.pos.y and
                self.pos.y + self.size.y < tile.pos.y + 8  then

                if isOnWall == false then

                    self.pos.y = tile.pos.y - self.size.y 
                    self.vel.y = 0
                end
            end

        elseif box.y + self.size.y / 2 > tile.pos.y + tile.size.y / 2 then

            if box.y < tile.pos.y + tile.size.y then
                
                self.vel.y = self.gravity

            end

        end

    end 

end

::skip::

self.pos.x = self.pos.x + self.vel.x * dt
self.pos.y = self.pos.y + self.vel.y * dt
```